# Invalid Token using GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync Outside Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've been stuck on this for days.

I am using `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` to create a token outside the Controller (it's working fine), but somehow my token is longer than the ones created within the Controller using the `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` and therefore the `ConfirmEmail` action rejects the token. (`Error: Invalid Token`).
I have tried `Machinekey` on `web.config`, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, but I am still stuck.

How to sort out the Invalid Token error on Controller `ConfirmEmail`?

Here is my Code:

**RegisterUser (outside Controller)**

```
public async Task RegisterUserAsync()
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
    var UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);

    var query = from c in db.Customer
                where !(from o in db.Users
                        select o.customer_pk)
                    .Contains(c.customer_pk)
                select c;
    var model = query.ToList();

    if (query != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = item.email, Email = item.email, customerId = item.customerId};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage
                {
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                };
                message.Subject = "Confirm Email";
                message.To.Add(item.email1);
                message.Body = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";

                client.SendAsync(message, "userToken");

                //Assign Role User Here
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Client");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**SendEmailConfirmation method (outside Controller)**

```
public async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID)
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
    var UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
    var url = new UrlHelper();
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
    UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
        provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
    string encodedCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

    string callbackUrl = "http://localhost/Accounts/ConfirmEmail?userId=" + userID + "&code=" + encodedCode;
    return callbackUrl;
}
```

where db is

```
ApplicationdDbContext db = new ApplicationdDbContext();
```

`ConfirmEmail` within the Identity Controller (Accounts Controller) - I've created Accounts instead of Account controller but it's working fine.

```
//
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    var confirmed = await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(userId);
    if (confirmed)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(userId);
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code); //Here I get the error (Token Invlaid, despite the token and userId being displayed)
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        ViewBag.userId = userId;
        ViewBag.code = code;
    }

    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(SetPasswordViewModel model, string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(userId, model.NewPassword);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        }

        return RedirectToLocal(userId);
    }

    ViewBag.userId = userId;
    ViewBag.code = code;

    AddErrors(result);

    return View(model);
}
```

I have worked for hours in this code but until now I can't sort it out.
Thanks for any comments or solution.  The reason for this approach is that I have to use task scheduler (I'm using fluentscheduler, which is working fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
    provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
```

`DpapiDataProtectionProvider` here is just not the same as what Identity uses while running under IIS. As far as I remember instead of `"MyApp"` it uses internal name for IIS web-site. Also it does some magic with registering it through delegates and as a singleton.

You can try to save a static reference to data protection provider and use it in your scheduler code. In `Startup.Auth.cs` class do this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        // other stuff.
    }
}
```

Then in your UserManager access for that reference like this:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyDbContext()))
    {
        var dataProtectionProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;
        this.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        // do other configuration
    }
}
```

However I'm not familiar wiht details of FluentScheduler and it might not let you access this static variable if it starts processes in separate AppDomain. But give it a try and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks trailmax, your answer helped me partially, as I am able to create a token more like the one created in controller (same length), which is good, but unfortunately I am still getting "Invalid Token" error when validating email on EmailConfirm action (get).  I get the Id and Token but token is invalid.  I have tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode but still stuck.  Do you have any thoughts about it.  Thanks

Comment: @prezequias Check your user records in database - is there any value in `SecurityStamp` field?

Comment: Yes it has Security Stamp Value

Comment: trailmax, your help was fantastic.  It's working now. You saved my life, Thanks